# smtplib.SMTPConnectError: (451, b'Request action aborted on MFE proxy, SMTP server is not available.')

Tags: python, django, gmail

Please i have been facing this error for the past three days , i have already checked all answers and i have made appropriate corrections, allowed less secure apps, off 2 factor authentication, cross checked username/password
But non of these help

settings.py code

```
SERVER_EMAIL = 'infopython@gmail.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = SERVER_EMAIL
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER

ADMINS = [
    ('admin', 'admin5@gmail.com'),
]

MANAGERS = ADMINS
```

Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\sendtestemail.py", line 33, in handle
    recipient_list=kwargs['email'],
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py", line 60, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 294, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 103, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 63, in open
    self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 254, in __init__
    raise SMTPConnectError(code, msg)
smtplib.SMTPConnectError: (451, b'Request action aborted on MFE proxy, SMTP server is not available.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when mail port was set to 25

```
EMAIL_PORT = 25
```

I had to change the port for it to work for me. Do check if your email host provides other ports and try any other available ports.

For me, changing the email port from 25 to  587 worked.

```
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```